# Will the GPSD supports the U-blox EVK-M8N and EVK-M8T that are based on LEA-M8 series

Tags: gps, gpsd, ntpd, clock-synchronization

I read from the following links: http://www.catb.org/gpsd/gpsd-time-service-howto.html#_choice_of_hardware, and http://catb.org/gpsd/hardware.html, in which the U-blox EVK 6H is suggested to work with the open-source GPSD and NTPD for time synchronization based on Pulse Per Second (PPS). However, the EVK 6H is not on-sale anymore by u-blox, and the newest evaluation kits available are EVK-M8N and EVK-M8T for the LEA-M8 series. Do you know if GPSD will work properly with EVK-M8N and EVK-M8T?

Are the LEA-M8S and LEA-M8T belong to the u-blox M8 series? I read the following statement from the webpage of GPSD: http://www.catb.org/gpsd/references.html

" u-blox M8 Rev 08 (December 2014)
he u-blox M8 support GPS, GLONASS and BeiDou. gpsd supports it.  "

Anyone has experience working on GPSD with EVK-M8* ?

There are alternative GPS devices,such as Garmin 18X and 16X which requires some soldering work with the RS232 connector. What would you suggest on the GPS modules to work with GPSD and NTPD on Linux, U-blox or Garmin?

Thx!

Jianguo